# Scanner input new Scaner(doc); <---------- Error ; expected

Tags: java, compiler-errors

I am trying to compile but I seem to be getting an error stating I am missing a `;` on a line that has the `;`. I have also looked around the code and can't see an error myself. I hope that you can point me in the right direction :)

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;


public class marks
{

    private String  asses;
    private int  mark;


    public marks()
    {


    }


    public void createFile() throws Exception
    {
        File doc;
        doc = new File ("marks.txt");
        if(!doc.exists()){
            doc.createNewFile();
            System.out.println("A New File Has been Created");
          }
    else {
     System.out.println ("File Already Exists");
    }
 }

 public void enterMarks()
 {
   Scanner input new Scaner(doc); <---------- Error ; expected 

   while (input.hasNext()){
       String asses = input.next();
       int mark = input.nextInt();
       System.out.println( asses +" "+ mark);
    }
 }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're missing an `=`:

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(doc);
```

Comment: and : Scanner / Scaner : check the spelling ! A IDE like eclipse or Netbeans would have pointed this out.

Comment: Maybe `Scaner`is a subclass of `Scanner` ;-)

Comment: No it was a misspelling lol but thanks to all of the contributors

Answer (score 0):

`Scanner input = new Scanner(doc);`
 "=" is missing and `Scanner` spells wrong; change visibility `doc` to global